# How many simultaneous fetch calls can a lambda make

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I've got a NodeJS14 Lambda on AWS whose purpose is to go out to various device endpoints and pull in data.  It runs on a schedule.

The idea is I'd just loop through my needs and do an 'fetch' call for each.

Something like (psudocode):

```
 for (device of deviceList) {
     fetch(device.uri)
         .then(resp => saveToS3(resp) )
         .catch(err => notifyAdminOfError(err) ) 
 }
```

How many of these fetch calls can I run at a time?  I expect my deviceList to get to around 10k long-term but will likely start around 1k.

If there is a limit (either in lambda, in node.js, or just a practical limit), I can break it up with a 'master' that hands out 100 devices (or whatever the limit) to a multiple secondary lambdas as needed... but I'd rather not complicate things like that needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are essentially single-core so having multiple threads may not provide any benefit (Reference: [AWS Forum response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=708378))

There is also a function timeout limit of 15 minutes ([Lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html))

The answer to your question depends on how long your fetch call takes. If it is a few milliseconds, then you can process 1k devices using a single Lambda under 15 minutes. If it is longer, you will need to process them in batches. You can use the same Lambda and call it with different batch inputs to process all devices.

Comment: So if each fetch takes, 5 seconds... they won't happen concurrently if I use a callback/then type syntax?

Comment: Did you think about having a Lambda that fetches and processes only one device and calling that Lambda function 10k times? That seems like a simpler solution and the cost won't be much different than running a Lambda for longer to fetch them all.

Comment: In the end, that's my question, eh?   Is a loop of async fetch calls faster than the cold-start times of hundreds/thousands of lambdas?

Comment: Given that your function only fetches some data and saves it to S3, it won't have a lot of dependencies so the cold-start times will be very minimal. Also, lambas that finished processing will work on your incoming requests so you won't have a cold-start every time. I think calling a single lambda hundreds/thousands of times is a better solution here.

Comment: Would I not run into concurrent lambda issues -- given I can only have 3000 of them?

Comment: Suppose you have a Lambda that fetches the device data and uploads it to S3. You can still have a for loop like the pseudocode you shared and instead of fetch and save, it would invoke the Lambda asynchronously. If you hit the concurrency limit, you can add a wait for about 5 seconds (approximate fetch and save time) before invoking the next 3000. Does that sound reasonable to you?

If your trigger is SNS/SQS, you can also achieve this by setting retry strategies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concurrency Quota limit inside the lambda function, but it is for the number of calls you made to your Lambda function [Invocation Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html).

Burst concurrency quotas

1. 3000 – US West (Oregon), US East (N. Virginia), Europe (Ireland)
2. 1000 – Asia Pacific (Tokyo), Europe (Frankfurt), US East (Ohio)
3. 500 – Other Regions

But if I’m right your question is related to the concurrent calls inside the lambda function.

In lambda there’s a way of making the async call where the Event queue handles all the incoming requests, that’s one of doing it.

But it comes with other setbacks as well like eventually consistent event queue [Invocation async](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)

Another solution that I can think of is by “decoupling” your reading device call with AWS SQS but it could be overkill for your use case.